# Monitoring web request in dynatrace

Tags: dynatrace

I am new to Dynatrace and the following is my setup:

I have a Kubernetes cluster where I have deployed the Istio service mesh.

A simple httpbin pod is running and I can successfully make a GET request to the same.

I have successfully attached my Kubernetes cluster to the dynatrace (version : 1.276.258.20231023-170203)

I can see my httpbin workload in dynatrace. The workload is exposed via istio ingress gateway.

The issue is :

I can successfully make the call http:///anything which returns a 200 OK response from httpbin using POSTMAN, but not able to view this request any where in dynatrace.

This is a simple setup to get my hands dirty with dynatrace. Later I want to run some load on my setup and see these requests in dynatrace.

All I see is /healthz/ready endpoint with istio side car exposes.

Do I need to do some thing extra to see /anything call in dynatrace ? am I missing something here.

Help appriciated.
Regards